# How to search for documents/records that doesn't have a certain field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

For example this is a query I do:

```
server:"xxx.xxx.com" AND request_url:"/xxx/xxx/xxx" AND http_X_Forwarded_Proto:(https OR http)
```

Now if I want to search for all the documents/records that doesn't have `http_X_Forwarded_Proto` field what should I do? I tried:

```
server:"xxx.xxx.com" AND request_url:"/xxx/xxx/xxx" AND http_X_Forwarded_Proto:"-"
```

and it didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-_exists_` on the Kibana Discover search bar.

For example to see the documents where the field `http_X_Forwarded_Proto` does not exists, you need to use: `-_exists_:http_X_Forwarded_Proto`

To see the documents where the field exists, just remove the `-` from the search: `_exists_:http_X_Forwarded_Proto`

If you are using a recent version of Kibana you also can click on `Add a filter` below the search bar, choose the field and select `exist` or `does not exist`

[image: kibana add a filter]